# Best way to test code with Airflow variables and connections on different environments

Tags: continuous-integration, airflow

For our Airflow Projects (running Airflow 2.0.1) I have implemented some general test that verify the DAG validity, check if each DAG has an owner/email, check for parsing time and so on ..

Now I am trying to set up some CI/CD pipeline that runs these tests and then pushes the DAGs to the Cloud Composer bucket. This test however will obviously fail if I use any Airflow Connection or Variable as these have not been created yet on the runners.

What I do not want to do is using mocking, as I have to specify each connection/variable which is a bit too much work for general tests. How do you deal with connections/variables for testing on different environments (development/testing/production)

Comment: Which version of Airflow are you using?

Comment: I am using Airflow 2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Airflow 2 you can use the stable API to create or update variables in the desired environment. You just need to call that API from the CI/CD pipeline.

Check the official documentation for [create a variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_variables) and [update a variable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/patch_variable).